# How do you encode a post-1994 ASN.1 EXTERNAL type?

Tags: der, ber, asn.1

### Background:

Prior to 1994, `EXTERNAL` was defined like so (with automatic and explicit tagging):

```
EXTERNAL  ::=  [UNIVERSAL 8] IMPLICIT SEQUENCE
    {
    direct-reference  OBJECT IDENTIFIER OPTIONAL,
    indirect-reference  INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    data-value-descriptor  ObjectDescriptor  OPTIONAL,
    encoding  CHOICE
                {single-ASN1-type  [0] ANY,
                octet-aligned     [1] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING,
                arbitrary         [2] IMPLICIT BIT STRING}
    }
```

But since then, it has been defined as:

```
EXTERNAL := [UNIVERSAL 8] IMPLICIT SEQUENCE {
    identification CHOICE {
        syntax OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
        presentation-context-id INTEGER,
        context-negotiation SEQUENCE {
            presentation-context-id INTEGER,
            transfer-syntax OBJECT IDENTIFIER } },
    data-value-descriptor ObjectDescriptor OPTIONAL,
    data-value OCTET STRING }
```

Dubuisson's *ASN.1* says (page 412):

> the context-specific tags, in particular, which appear before the alternatives 
>   of the `encoding` component (of type `CHOICE`) must be encoded but not those
>   computed in the 1994 version.

On page 413, he describes how to encode an `INSTANCE OF`, which he notes is encoded identically to an `EXTERNAL`. The `identification` shows as being encoded by just a universal tag with a number of 6 (`OBJECT IDENTIFIER`). The `encoding` shows as being of the form

```
[CONTEXT 0]
    [UNIVERSAL 2]
```

meaning that he is encoding an `INTEGER`, 5, as his choice of `single-ASN-type`.

### My question

If post-1994 version of `EXTERNAL` is backwards-compatible, then `data-value` would have to translate to one of the pre-1994 alternatives for `encoding`. *Which one is it?*

In other words, if I encode a post-1994 `EXTERNAL` (using `presentation-context-id` as our choice of `identification` just for the sake of the example), does it get encoded as

```
[UNIVERSAL 8]
    [UNIVERSAL 2] (presentation-context-id => indirect-reference)
    [CONTEXT 0] (data-value => single-ASN1-type)
        [UNIVERSAL 4]
```

or

```
[UNIVERSAL 8]
    [UNIVERSAL 2] (presentation-context-id => indirect-reference)
    [CONTEXT 1] (data-value => octet-aligned)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to Rec. ITU-T X.690 | ISO/IEC 8825-1 clause 18.  It describes in detail how the backward compatibility is maintained, indicating exactly how to map a value for the X.680 EXTERNAL associated sequence to the following SEQUENCE defined in X.690:

```
[UNIVERSAL 8] IMPLICIT SEQUENCE {
    direct-reference                OBJECT IDENTIFIER OPTIONAL,
    indirect-reference              INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    data-value-descriptor           ObjectDescriptor OPTIONAL,
    encoding                        CHOICE {
    single-ASN1-type                        [0] ABSTRACT-SYNTAX.&Type,
    octet-aligned                           [1] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING,
    arbitrary                               [2] IMPLICIT BIT STRING } }
```

Also, this sequence assumes an EXPLICIT TAGS environment rather than AUTOMATIC TAGS as the sequence in X.680.

Comment: Ah "NOTE – This sequence type differs from that in ITU-T Rec. X.680 | ISO/IEC 8824-1 for historical reasons." I guess I missed that little footnote, but that footnote makes all the difference! Thank you so much!